# How to enable CORS for html5 video loading vtt file?

Tags: html5-video, webvtt, vtt

**My Need**

html5 video element loads both a video and a vtt file saved in a different domain.

**The problem**

vtt is not loaded and error `Text track from origin has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute.`

**My investigation**

I am aware that CORS needs to be used so vtt can be loaded in html5 successfully.

I have enabled CORS on server side for requests from any domain.

Some articles say adding `crossorigin` or `crossorigin="anonymous"` into ` element can do the job, but it doesn't work. Either the video is not loaded at all or different errors appear

I have put my code here below

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <video id="myvideo" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" autoplay>
      <source src=http://video.dublearn.net/-KqIgE-3roMSBbiHUmLI/video.mp4 type="video/mp4"></source>
      <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src=http://video.dublearn.net/-KqIgE-3roMSBbiHUmLI/video.vtt default>
    </video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully this helps the next person to stumble upon this SO question. I discovered that IE (10 and 11) does not support loading a cross-origin VTT file for a `<track>`, even if CORS is enabled. In order to add IE support for captions, I had to use a script like the one below.

This script downloads each VTT file via AJAX, creates a [blob URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), and replaces each `<track>` src with its respective blob URL.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") < 0 && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") < 0) {
    // Not IE, do nothing.
    return;
  }

  var tracks = document.querySelectorAll("track")

  for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    loadTrackWithAjax(tracks[i]);
  }
});

function loadTrackWithAjax(track) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 && this.responseText) {
      // If VTT fetch succeeded, replace the src with a BLOB URL.
      var blob = new Blob([this.responseText], { type: 'text/vtt' });
      track.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", track.src, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<video controls preload width="600" height="337.5" autoplay crossorigin="anonymous">
      <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
      <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt" default>
</video>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I would want to add this amount of code on my production for a vtt file but this is smart... Nice work.

Comment: Well, you can minify it :)

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm that the `crossorigin=anonymous` attribute on the `video` element does indeed load the text track as expected.

Give this code a shot:

```html
<video id="myvideo" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" autoplay crossorigin="anonymous">
      <source src=http://video.dublearn.net/-KqIgE-3roMSBbiHUmLI/video.mp4 type="video/mp4"></source>
      <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src=http://video.dublearn.net/-KqIgE-3roMSBbiHUmLI/video.vtt default>
</video>
```

Finally, remember, you must use a web server to serve this HTML snipped - this cannot be done locally (ie. `file//`).

If you're familiar with `node` - install `http-server`, run with `--cors` and use ngrok.

Comment: Hello, when I put the code in jsfiddle for instance, it does not go.  I also tried the same in a node server. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/zbg8b0bj/

Comment: Worked for me on a CodePen