# Is there a way to attach captions to an HTML video on a website by inspecting the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Say there is some website hosting a video that doesn't have an option for captions. Is there a way to "forcefully" attach captions to the `<video>` element from my side, for example by editing the DOM with Chrome? I've tried the following:

```js
$("#video_id").append('<track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://websitefromotherdomain.com/subs.srt" default>')
```

This returns:

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL https://websitefromotherdomain.com/subs.srt from frame with URL https://video_domain.com/123.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

So this error is pretty self explanatory. But I was wondering if what I'd want to accomplish is even possible, and if there is another method for appending captions to a video (where the captions are hosted on a different website).

Comment: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902293/how-to-enable-cors-for-html5-video-loading-vtt-file) ?

Comment: Do you have example live links of a video and a `.srt` file so we can check and debug on our side?

Comment: You could always write a browser extension that would take a local file reference, create a blob URL, and add them that way.